# How to get the latest version of jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

This code calls the latest version of `jquery`:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
```

Now I want the latest version of `jquery ui`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Doesn't work - status code `404` on network tab

Is there a way ?

Comment: please just use the <script> tag recommended by the JQuery UI page.  Looks like you may have to specify the exact version.

Comment: @SGandhi - There is no problem with calling an exact version, but my question is about last version

Comment: understood - doesn't look like the pointer to latest version is maintained on the jquery.com domain.   There might be third party CDNs that maintain a link to latest version of it.   One option is to use UNPKG which maintains a distributable version for every NPM package.  I just found one for jquery-ui and am posting it here .... 

https://www.unpkg.com/jquery-ui@latest/dist/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: @SGandhi - understood - if there is no link to the latest version on jquery.com - I need that third party CDN or whatever. So simple.

Comment: just edited my comment and added one such URL https://unpkg.com/jquery-ui@latest/dist/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI's [Content Distribution Network (CDN)](https://releases.jquery.com/ui/) for this.

Or, better yet, use [cdnjs.cloudflare.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui). It gives us `<script>` tags to put into our html that include [subresource `integrity` hashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity). Those hashes protect us against cybercriminals who might hack us by altering the Javascript. The tag for a recent version of jQuery UI is this.

```html
<script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" 
   integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q=="
   crossorigin="anonymous"
   referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
```

It's a good idea to use that [CDN for jQuery itself](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery), for the same reason. And it's Cloudflare; they're famous for having a great worldwide presence and  excellent network traffic engineering skillz.

But you should be aware that jQuery UI is distributed to us users as a [customized download](https://jqueryui.com/download/). We can select the widgets and other features we need, and the download page creates a .js and a .min.js file for us. The custom download builder omits the widgets and features we don't need. That can save an astonishing amount of download "footprint" for apps that don't use many different parts of jQueryUI. Using a subset often proves faster than using even the fastest CDN.

**Pro tip**. Don't use anything like `/latest/` from a third party CDN source in a production web page. Always always specify the exact version when using a CDN. You don't want a random late-arriving update to a new latest version to break your diligently tested web app. Update your versions on *your* schedule, not the library publisher's schedule.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very usefull for me, but I need to call the `latest` version and not any specific version, on the same way as I call the `latest` version of jquery core. I just want to know is it technically possible or not and why not ?